# overiding the items in table view due to implementation of pagination

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, pagination

Here I had implemented pagination for the table view and items are loaded by using model class but here the loaded items are replacing with the new items and displaying only 10 items at a time I am implementing it for the first time can anyone help me how to resolve the issue?

```
func listCategoryDownloadJsonWithURL(listUrl: String) {
        let url = URL(string: listUrl)!
        print(listUrl)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil { print(error!); return }
            do {
                if let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String:Any] {
                    self.listClassModel = ModelClass(dict: jsonObj as [String : AnyObject])
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        guard let obj = self.listClassModel else { return }
                        let itemsCount = obj.items.count
                        print(itemsCount)
                        for i in 0..<itemsCount {
                            let customAttribute = obj.items[i].customAttribute
                            for j in 0..<customAttribute.count {
                                if customAttribute[j].attributeCode == "image" {
                                    let baseUrl = "http://192.168.1.11/magento2/pub/media/catalog/product"
                                    self.listCategoryImageArray.append(baseUrl + customAttribute[j].value)
                                    print(self.listCategoryImageArray)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                        self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
                        self.collectionView.delegate = self
                        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                        self.collectionView.isHidden = false
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let obj = listClassModel?.items
        return obj?.count ?? 0
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "productsCell", for: indexPath) as! productsCell
        let arr = listClassModel?.items[indexPath.row]
        let images = listCategoryImageArray[indexPath.row]
        let urls = NSURL(string: images)
        self.tableView.isHidden = false
        cell.productImage.hnk_setImageFromURL(urls! as URL)
        cell.productName.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        cell.productName.numberOfLines = 2
        cell.productName.text = arr?.name
        cell.productPrice.text = "$\( (arr?.price)!).00"
        cell.buynowButton .addTarget(self, action: #selector(buyNowButton(_:)), for:UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        cell.cartButton .addTarget(self, action: #selector(cartButton(_:)), for:UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let obj = listClassModel?.items
        let lastElement = (obj?.count)! - 1
        if !loadingData && indexPath.row == lastElement {
            loadingData = true
            loadMoreData()
        }
    }
```

here is the code for getting new data into table view

```
    func loadMoreData() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            guard let obj = self.listClassModel else { return }
            let  totalItems = obj.totalCount
            let numberOfItems = obj.searchCriteria.pageSize
            var count = 0
            let float = Float(totalItems)/Float(numberOfItems)
            print(float.cleanValue)
            let totalPages = Int(ceil(float))
            if totalPages != count {
                    let batchSize = 10
                    self.index += 1
                    count += 1
                    print(self.index)
                    let sortOrder = "ASC"
                    let conditionType = "eq"
                    let sortField = "name"
                    let listUrlWithParameters  = "http://192.168.1.11/magento2/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=17&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=\(conditionType)&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=\(sortField)&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=\(sortOrder)&searchCriteria[pageSize]=\(batchSize)&searchCriteria[currentPage]=\(self.index)"
                    self.listCategoryDownloadJsonWithURL(listUrl: listUrlWithParameters)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // this runs on the main queue
            self.loadingData = false
            }

        }
    }
struct ModelClass {
    var items : [List]
    var totalCount : Int
    var searchCriteria : SearchCriteria

    init(dict:[String:AnyObject]) {
        totalCount = dict["total_count"] as! Int

        let searchDict = dict["search_criteria"] as? [String:AnyObject]
        searchCriteria = SearchCriteria(dict: searchDict!)

        let arr = dict["items"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]
        var listArr = [List]()
        for obj in arr! {
            listArr.append(List(dict: obj))
        }
        items = listArr
    }
}

struct List {

    let name : String
    let sku : Any
    let id : Int
    let attributeSetId : Int
    let price : Int
    let status : Int
    let visibility : Int
    let typeId: String
    let createdAt : Any
    let updatedAt : Any
    var customAttribute = [ListAttribute]()

    init(dict : [String:Any]) {
        if let customAttribute = dict["custom_attributes"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            var result = [ListAttribute]()
            for obj in customAttribute {
                result.append(ListAttribute(json: obj)!)
            }
            self.customAttribute = result
        } else {
            self.customAttribute = [ListAttribute]()
        }
        self.name = (dict["name"] as? String)!
        self.sku = dict["sku"]!
        self.id = (dict["id"] as? Int)!
        self.attributeSetId = (dict["attribute_set_id"] as? Int)!
        self.price = (dict["price"] as? Int)!
        self.status = (dict["status"] as? Int)!
        self.visibility = (dict["visibility"] as? Int)!
        self.typeId = (dict["type_id"] as? String)!
        self.createdAt = dict["created_at"]!
        self.updatedAt = dict["updated_at"]!
    }
}
struct ListAttribute {

    let attributeCode : String
    let value : String

    init?(json : [String:AnyObject]) {

        self.attributeCode = (json["attribute_code"])! as! String
        self.value = (json["value"])! as! String

    }
}
struct SearchCriteria {
    var filterGroup : [FilterGroup]
    var sortGroup : [SortGroup]
    var pageSize : Int
    var pageNumber : Int

    init(dict:[String:AnyObject]) {
        if let arr = dict["filter_groups"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]{
            var filterArr = [FilterGroup]()
            for obj in arr {
                filterArr.append(FilterGroup(dict: obj))
            }
            self.filterGroup = filterArr
        } else {
            self.filterGroup = [FilterGroup]()
        }
        if let arr = dict["sort_orders"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]{
            var filterArr = [SortGroup]()
            for obj in arr {
                filterArr.append(SortGroup(dict: obj))
            }
            self.sortGroup = filterArr
        } else {
            self.sortGroup = [SortGroup]()
        }
        self.pageSize = dict["page_size"] as! Int
        self.pageNumber = dict["current_page"] as! Int
    }
}
```

Comment: You're re-initiating object at `self.listClassModel = ModelClass(dict: jsonObj as [String : AnyObject])`. Append items with `self.listClassModel`. Don't do `=`

Comment: then how to give no. of rows in section count for table view @Jamil

Comment: When the `listClassModel` is appended, the items count also will. `numberOfRowsInSection` is already good to go.

Comment: but it is returning error as shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8vni.png

Comment: i had declared as model class like this  var listClassModel = [ModelClass]() and the line changed as 
 self.listClassModel.append(ModelClass(dict: jsonObj as [String : AnyObject]))

Comment: This issue is something else. The above mentioned question's answer is given

Comment: after changing the appended items line the error came previously it was fine @Jamil

Comment: You must be appending the whole `ModelClass(dict: jsonObj as [String : AnyObject])` with `listClassModel`. Iterate through the `jsonObj` and then append with `listClassModel`

Comment: in model class i am having two more model classes then how to get the items in it ? @Jamil

Comment: i had edited my question i am having two more model classes inside this whole model class @Jamil